# LEFT JOIN for current row in primary table

Tags: sql, database, jdbc, cursor, left-join

This is the question about JDBC. I have next task. I'm iterating through rows from table A and for some current row I want to execute some query against table B in context of current row from A. For example, if I have some query like

```
SELECT B.description FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.refId
```

then I want to get all results where B.refId="current row from A".ID. Please, note that I cannot modify query for selecting results from B.

For example, let's table A like this:

```
ID name

1  nameA
2  nameB
```

and table B:

```
ID description refID

1  desc1       1
2  desc2       1
3  decs3       2
4  desc4       2
```

So if I for example on row from table A with ID 2 and perform my query then I want to get "desc3" and "desc4" only.

I suggest that this task can be solved with cursors but I'm familiar with it. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: IBM DB2 actually. Does it matter if we use JDBC?

Comment: `Please, note that I cannot modify query for selecting results from B` so what do you want exactly

Comment: I just asking if is there a way in JDBC to run query in context of single row instead of selecting all results.

Comment: You said you don't want to change the query. Then it plain stops here. You cannot go around this without changing the query.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question

```
SELECT B.description FROM
   A
   INNER JOIN
   B ON A.ID = B.refId
WHERE
   A.ID = 2

SELECT B.description FROM
   B
WHERE
   B.refid = 2
```

Otherwise, I don't think we understand the question...

Comment: Oh, as I said I cannot change those query. I don't know why my question is not clear for you. I just asking if is there a way to run query in context of single row instead of selecting all results.

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? The query you gave *means* "all results where B.refId=current row from A.ID".

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make your *description*.

```
A.*
```

Not sure if I understand the question though.